# Dynamic Expression API (Dynamic.cs) Not properly parsing expression in .net 3.5

Tags: linq, dynamic, tree, lambda, expression

I'm having trouble getting this API working in .net 3.5 (works fine in 4.0). Basically I have following code

```
  List<ParameterExpression> parameters = new List<ParameterExpression>();
  parameters.Add(Expression.Parameter(typeof(double), "R0C6"));
  parameters.Add(Expression.Parameter(typeof(double), "R0C7"));
  parameters.Add(Expression.Parameter(typeof(double), "R0C8"));
  parameters.Add(Expression.Parameter(typeof(double), "R0C9"));
  parameters.Add(Expression.Parameter(typeof(double), "R0C10"));
  parameters.Add(Expression.Parameter(typeof(double), "R0C11"));
  parameters.Add(Expression.Parameter(typeof(double), "R0C12"));

  LambdaExpression e = DynamicExpressionBuilder.ParseLambda(
              parameters.ToArray(), typeof(double), "R0C6 + R0C7 + R0C8 + R0C9 + R0C10 + R0C11 + R0C12");

  var result = e.Compile().DynamicInvoke(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1);
  Console.WriteLine(result);
```

When running this code I get ArgumentException. The reason being .NET 3.5 does not have Func delegate which takes more than 4 parameters. Can someone suggest me change in Dynamic.cs so that I can get able code working in 3.5?

Comment: Can you explain what DynamicExpressionBuilder is doing with the parameters?  My answer below assumes that you have a static set of parameters, but after reading it again, I see that in practice you are probably dealing with an unknown number of parameters.

Comment: DynamicExpressionBuilder is just the renamed version of class DynamicExpression in the Dynamic.cs file. I've just changed name so that I can differentiate class DynamicExpression in the system.linq.expression namespace.

Answer (score 1):

Yes thats one alternative. Here is the code that worked for me

```
        List<ParameterExpression> parameters = new List<ParameterExpression>();
        parameters.Add(Expression.Parameter(typeof(Holder), "H"));


        LambdaExpression e = DynamicExpressionBuilder.ParseLambda(parameters.ToArray(), typeof(double), "H.R0C6 + H.R0C7 + H.R0C8 + H.R0C9 + H.R0C10 + H.R0C11 + H.R0C12");

        var result = e.Compile().DynamicInvoke(new Holder { R0C6 = 1, R0C7 = 1, R0C8 = 1, R0C9 = 1, R0C10 = 1, R0C11 = 1, R0C12 = 1 });
        Console.WriteLine(result);
```

But surely there should be better way of achieving my original implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason that you can't combine all the doubles into a single parameter object that contains fields or properties for the values?  Then you'd only need one parameter in your Func for the expression.